# Is a continuous and locally Lipschitz function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be locally Lipschitz and continuous on $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is open, bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n.$
>   **From these two conditions can we say that $f$ is Lipschitz?**

**Edit:**  **It is not true while we are taking $\Omega$ as open , bounded ,but will it be true when $\Omega$ is compact?**

Please someone help.Thank you.

Comment: I think $\Omega$ needs to be compact for the result to be true

Comment: "Locally Lipschitz and continuous" - doesn't locally Lipschitz already mean continuous?

Comment: Yeah. Now I think that it should have been piecewise Lipschitz and continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $f\colon(0,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac1x$.

---

About the new question that you added (you shouldn't; asking a new question is the right way of acting), I could provide an answer, but [someone has already done that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149954/if-f-is-locally-lipschitz-on-x-and-x-is-compact-then-f-is-lipschitz-on).

Comment: If we take $\Omega$ to be compact then is this true?

Comment: @mathiu_lady Yes, but then $\Omega$ will not be open.

Comment: Yeah of course. Can you give some hints. to prove that

Comment: @mathiu_lady Post it as a question.

Comment: Okay. I'm editing my question. Please see it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x) =\frac{1}{x} .$

Comment: I'd advise not using $\mathbb{R}_+$ as there is no concensus on if the notation includes 0 or not.

Comment: @JamalS I have never seen it used to include 0 personally.